# Select all results where group by > 1

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate-functions

I have a table full of accounts with an address. I would like to select every account which resides at the same address as another account.

If my data looks like so:

```
------------------------------------
| Account Number | Address          |
| 12345          | 55 Bee St        |
| 23456          | 94 Water way     |
| 34567          | 15 Beagle Drive  |
| 45678          | 55 Bee St        |
| 56789          | 94 Water way     |
| 67890          | 12 Green St      |
-------------------------------------
```

I would like to do something along the lines of:

```
SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE group by address > 1;
```

So that my results would be:

```
------------------------------------
| Account Number | Address          |
| 12345          | 55 Bee St        |
| 23456          | 94 Water way     |
| 45678          | 55 Bee St        |
| 56789          | 94 Water way     |
-------------------------------------
```

If it makes any difference, it's a PostgreSQL database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a left join against the same table to find the records with the same address, and group on the fields, then you can count the matching addresses to get the records that has at least one matching address:

```
select a.AccountNumber, a.Address
from accounts a
left join accounts o on o.Address = a.Address and o.AccountNumber <> a.AccountNumber
group by a.AccountNumber, a.Address
having count(o.AccountNumber) >= 1
```

This approach gives you the addresses with each account number, and it doesn't give you duplicates if an address occurs more than twice.

Answer (score 1):

You need to join the table to itself using a join condition that the two addresses are the same but making sure that the account number is different between the two rows:

```
select distinct account_number, address
from accounts a1
join accounts a2 on a1.account_number > a2.account_number
   and a1.address = a2.address
```

Note the use of `>` comparison between account numbers which not only prevents rows joining to themselves, but prevents the reverse join.

I added `distinct` in case there are three accounts with the same address, otherwise you don't need it.

Comment: That will only return any records if they have the same account number and address.

Comment: This will only return the addresses with two accounts where I need all the accounts that share an address with another account (if that makes sense?)

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
SELECT *
FROM Account A1
WHERE
    EXISTS (
        SELECT *
        FROM Account A2
        WHERE
            A1.AccountNumber <> A2.AccountNumber
            AND A1.Address = A2.Address
    )
```

In plain English: select every account such that there is a different account (`A1.AccountNumber <> A2.AccountNumber`) with the same address (`A1.Address = A2.Address`).

Comment: +1 This is the fastest way (especially with many duplicates). Should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the test demonstrating performance of the three valid answers.
`EXISTS` is superior to the one with `LEFT JOIN` / `GROUP BY`:

#### Test setup

Table with 100k rows, 1000 different values for `b`.
The performance gap widens with more rows - fewer duplicates means less difference.
No indexes.

```
CREATE TABLE tbl (a text, b text);
INSERT INTO tbl
SELECT (random()*10000)::int::text
      ,(random()*1000)::int || ' some more text here'
FROM   generate_series(1, 100000) g;
```

#### 1. [@Guffa](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15672979/939860): `LEFT JOIN` / `GROUP BY` / `HAVING`

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE
SELECT t.a, t.b
FROM   tbl t
LEFT   join tbl t2 on t2.b = t.b and t2.a <> t.a
GROUP  by t.a, t.b
HAVING count(t2.a) >= 1;
```

#### 2. The same, untangled to just `JOIN` / `GROUP BY`

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE
SELECT t.a, t.b
FROM   tbl t
JOIN   tbl t2 ON t2.b = t.b AND t2.a <> t.a
GROUP  BY t.a, t.b;
```

#### 3.[@Branko](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15673074/939860): `EXISTS`

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE
SELECT *
FROM   tbl t
WHERE  EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM   tbl t2
    WHERE  t2.a <> t.a
    AND    t2.b = t.b
    );
```

#### 4.[@Bohemian](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15672908/939860): `DISTINCT`

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE
SELECT DISTINCT t.a, t.b
FROM   tbl t
JOIN   tbl t2 on t2.b = t.b and t2.a <> t.a;
```

[**-> SQLfiddle** displaying EXPLAIN ANALYZE output for the queries](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!12/75cad/1).

1. Total runtime: **12208.954 ms**
2. Total runtime: 11504.460 ms
3. Total runtime: **272.508 ms** -- ! ~ 45x faster than 1.
4. Total runtime: 11540.627 ms

After adding multi-column index ([**SQLfiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!12/4985e/1)) ..

```
CREATE INDEX a_b_idx ON tbl(b, a);
```

.. the *runtime doesn't change*. Postgres doesn't use the index. It obviously expects a sequential table-scan to be faster since the whole table has to be read anyway.

Besides the execution time, also notice the **row count**, proving my point as discussed:
The JOIN creates a lot of intermediate duplicates, which the `EXISTS` version avoids to begin with:

Output of `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` for **1.**:

```
HashAggregate (cost=230601.26..230726.26 rows=10000 width=31) (actual time=12127.090..12183.087 rows=99476 loops=1)
Filter: (count(t2.a) >= 1)
-> Hash Left Join (cost=3670.00..154661.89 rows=10125250 width=31) (actual time=99.591..5897.744 rows=9991102 loops=1)
Hash Cond: (t.b = t2.b)
Join Filter: (t2.a  t.a)
Rows Removed by Join Filter: 101052
-> Seq Scan on tbl t (cost=0.00..1736.00 rows=100000 width=27) (actual time=0.036..36.197 rows=100000 loops=1)
-> Hash (cost=1736.00..1736.00 rows=100000 width=27) (actual time=99.141..99.141 rows=100000 loops=1)
Buckets: 2048 Batches: 8 Memory Usage: 784kB
-> Seq Scan on tbl t2 (cost=0.00..1736.00 rows=100000 width=27) (actual time=0.004..44.899 rows=100000 loops=1)
Total runtime: 12208.954 ms
```

Output of `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` for **3.**:

```
Hash Semi Join (cost=3670.00..7783.00 rows=1 width=27) (actual time=81.630..247.371 rows=100000 loops=1)
Hash Cond: (t.b = t2.b)
Join Filter: (t2.a  t.a)
Rows Removed by Join Filter: 1009
-> Seq Scan on tbl t (cost=0.00..1736.00 rows=100000 width=27) (actual time=0.010..32.758 rows=100000 loops=1)
-> Hash (cost=1736.00..1736.00 rows=100000 width=27) (actual time=81.388..81.388 rows=100000 loops=1)
Buckets: 2048 Batches: 8 Memory Usage: 784kB
-> Seq Scan on tbl t2 (cost=0.00..1736.00 rows=100000 width=27) (actual time=0.003..32.114 rows=100000 loops=1)
Total runtime: 272.508 ms
```

Answer (score 0):

You want a `HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT * FROM accounts
GROUP BY address
HAVING COUNT(address) > 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

i believe you are looking for the HAVING clause:

```
 select address,sum(accountnumber) group by address having sum(accountnumber) >1
```